# Force style to load in header when using ACF block

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've built an [ACF block](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/). As per the documentation, I've created the following via functions.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Register ACF Blocks
 */
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
function my_acf_init() {
    // check function exists
    if( function_exists('acf_register_block') ) {
        // Gallery block
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name'              => 'gallery',
            'title'             => __('Gallery'),
            'description'       => __('A custom gallery block.'),
            'render_callback'   => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
            'category'          => 'formatting',
            'icon'              => 'format-gallery',
            'keywords'          => array( 'gallery' ),
            'enqueue_assets' => function() {
                wp_enqueue_style( 'fancybox-style' );
                wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true ); 
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

The `'enqueue_assets'` function allows me to enqueue styles and scripts if the block is loaded.

The script loads in the footer as intended. However, the styles also load in the footer.

I've tried registering the style via functions and then enqueing it in the block, but it still loads in the footer. Here's how I'm registering the style.

```
wp_register_style( 'fancybox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css');
```

Is there a way within WordPress to force styles to load in the header?